# How to capture page load times in Selenium-IDE using the app.telemetry page speed monitor

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to do a quick and dirty page load test with Selenium IDE and using a plugin called app.telemetry page speed monitor. The tool provides a display in the tool bar of Firefox,(0.36 in red)  but I'm not sure how to capture that data via Selenium IDE?  Any thoughts.

This is the plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/apptelemetry/

[image: Toolbar image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
open      | lol.com
storeEval | window.performance.timing['loadEventEnd']-window.performance.timing['navigationStart'] | result
echo      | ${result}
```

It will get page loading speed from trying to find the IP of the lol.com till the page is fully loaded (full time). And you do not need any plugins. If you want to get only speed of server response  use:

```
storeEval | window.performance.timing['responseEnd']-window.performance.timing['requestStart'] | result
```

If you want to get some more specific time take a look at:[image]