# Selenium IDE Log Page Load Times

Tags: selenium-ide

I would like to get a high-level view of load page performance. How can I get Selenium IDE to log time whilst my Test Case is running and store time at each step. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You can use the way showed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660056/how-to-capture-page-load-times-in-selenium-ide-using-the-app-telemetry-page-spee/38693651#38693651