# Store windows.performance Values In Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, dom, performance-testing, selenium-ide

This is a slight repeat of [How to capture page load times in Selenium-IDE using the app.telemetry page speed monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660056)

However, the answer in that post does not seem to work (or doesnt anymore), possibly because the storeEval command in Selenium IDE doesnt seem to exist anymore.

I'm trying to retrieve certain windows.performance values for webpages as Selenium IDE moves through them.

I have tried:

```
Command 'open' > Target 'www.url.com'
Command 'store value' > Target window.performance.timing['navigationStart'] > Value 'result'
Command 'echo' > Target ${result}
```

But I get:

```
Warning implicit locators are deprecated, please change the locator to id=window.performance.timing['navigationStart']
```

The above doesn't work, as obviously its not an id.

Am I using the wrong Command? Or have to enter additional target details? Or can it be done at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use execute script instead:

```
 Command            Target                                                   Value
 open               http://www.example.com/
 execute script     return window.performance.timing['navigationStart']     result
 echo               ${result}
```

[image]